# Search across Stack Exchange sites in Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, ios-app

Is it possible to search for a question across all Stack Exchange sites in the Android app?

Right now I can search in only one specific site at a time.

If not, can you add that feature?

Comment: It's not really possible in the full site (just a customized Google Search) so I really can't see it being done in the app, of all  things. But who knows...

Comment: At least put a search button at the top level so it's clear you *can* search in the Android app.